# Make browser go to top of page when reloading page

Tags: javascript, browser

I've made a simple HTML page. When I press the Reload icon in the browser (Safari Mac, Chrome Mac, Safari iOS), the page reloads, and retains the vertical position in the page.

1. Is this the default behaviour in browsers these days? I seem to remember that browsers used to go to the top of the page before (at least some years back). When did this change?
2. What is the best way to make the browser go to the top of the page when the page is reloaded? Simply hook into "On Document Load", and jump to an anchor at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.scrollTo(0,0)` on document load

**EDIT 1:**

Something like this should do the trick:

```
document.onload = function(){
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing `$(document).ready(function() {window.scrollTo(0,0);}` with jQuery, but nothing happens when I press reload in the browser! The rest of the script is working, and there are no error message in the Console.

Comment: Check that your JavaScript actually load correct. It sounds like it doesn't fire at all.

Comment: I put a `console.log()` statement on each side of the `scroll`-statements, and they echo to the console. So the code is run. Still no repositioning.

Comment: Have you tried just putting the `window.scrollTo(0,0);` without the `document.onload` wrap? So just the single line. According to : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp, this should work everywhere.

Comment: Doesn't work. But `setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, 1);` works. Do the browsers have a mechanism for preventing scrollTo on document loading? Can I go to top on reload without using a timer?